# How to optimize the performance of a thread running in background in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, multithreading, .net-3.5

In my website, I am using thread to perform a repetitive process in background. Now the process takes around 30 to 45 seconds to update the database.

Basically the function performs the following:

1) Download the CSV from a website.

2) Parse the CSV and update the database tables.

I want to optimize the performance and decrease the time it takes to 15 seconds.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

Here is the Code:

```
        // MAIN FUNCTION IN THE THREAD
        private static void downloadAndParse()
        {
            NewHive.MyServ newServe = new NewHive.MyServ();
            NewHive.CsvDownload newService = new NewHive.CsvDownload();
            //NewHive.MyServ newServe = new NewHive.MyServ();
            string downloadSuccess = newService.CsvDownloader();
            if (downloadSuccess == "Success")
            {
                string parseSuccess = newService.CsvParser();

            }
            newServe.updateOthersInPosition();
        }







     //CSV DOWNLOAD FUNCTION
    public string CsvDownloader()
    {
        Byte[] inBuf = null;
       // HttpWebRequest wr = Convert.ChangeType(WebRequestFactory.Create("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=RHT+MSFT&f=sb2b3jk"),HttpWebRequest);
       // HttpWebResponse ws = Convert.ChangeType(wr.GetResponse(),HttpWebResponse);

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=INDU+INDU+^N225+^GSPC+^GDAXI+^FCHI+^HSI+^IXIC+^STOXX50E+^FTSE&f=l1bd14na");
        HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
        Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream();
        inBuf = new Byte[100000000];
        int bytesToRead = (int)inBuf.Length;

        int bytesRead=0;
        while(bytesToRead>0)
        {
            int n = str.Read(inBuf,bytesRead,bytesToRead);
            if(n==0)
            {
                break;
            }
            bytesRead += n;
            bytesToRead -= n;
        }
        FileStream fstr = new FileStream("D:\\Hosting\\7312812\\html\\News.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);


        //  FileStream fstr = new FileStream("News.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
       // FileStream fstr = new FileStream("C:\\VSS Working Folder\\27 Jan 11 NewHive\\NewHive\\CSV\\new.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        fstr.Write(inBuf,0,bytesRead);
        str.Close();
        fstr.Close();

        return "Success";
    }







     //CSV PARSER FUNCTION
   public string CsvParser()
    {
       int _nNrRowsProccessed = 0;

       string connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFolder"] + ";";

    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        string strFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFile"];
        string strSQL = "Select * from " + strFileName;

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        NewHive.MyServ newService = new NewHive.MyServ();
       // MasterCalendar_DB.OpenMySQLConnection();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            decimal LastTradePrice;
            decimal Bid;
            string MarketOpen;
            string IndexCode;
            string Index;
            decimal Offer;
            decimal LTPDatabase=0.1M;

                IndexCode = reader[3].ToString();
                String addSQL = "Select LastTradePrice from `jsontest`.`tbl_MarketData` where IndexCode = '" + IndexCode + "'";
                MySqlConnection objMyCon = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
                objMyCon.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = objMyCon.CreateCommand();

                command.CommandText = addSQL;
                MySqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();
                //int j = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    LTPDatabase = Convert.ToDecimal(result[0]);
                  //  LTPDatabase = Math.Round(LTPTemp, 2);
                }
                objMyCon.Close();
                decimal LTPTemp =  Convert.ToDecimal(reader[0].ToString());
                LastTradePrice = Math.Round(LTPTemp, 2);
                if (reader[1].ToString() != "N/A")
                {
                    Bid = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[1].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Bid = 10.0M;
                }
                if (LastTradePrice != LTPDatabase)
                {
                    MarketOpen = "Open";
                }
                else
                {
                    MarketOpen = "Close";
                }
                Index = reader[4].ToString();

                if (reader[5].ToString() != "N/A")
                {
                    Offer = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Offer = 20.0M;
                }
            //}
           // string[] arLine = strLine.Split(';');

           // string strAgencyPropertyID = arLine[0];
           // DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(arLine[1]);
          //  Int64 nDate = (Int64)Util.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(dt);
           // String strAvailability = (arLine[2]);

            _nNrRowsProccessed++;

            newService.CSVInsert(IndexCode,Index,MarketOpen,Bid,Offer,LastTradePrice);
          //  MasterCalendar_DB.Insert(strAgencyPropertyID, nDate, strAvailability);
        }           

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
       // MasterCalendar_DB.CloseMySQLConnection();
    }
    return "Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably start by profiling to determine which aspect takes the most time... then focusing on that? Without any code or more details this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Have you gotten metrics on the relative timings of the three main processes (file transfer, parsing algorithm, data access) to determine the bottleneck?

Comment: what is the algorithm / code that you are using to download and parse the csv? Which step is taking more time?

Comment: one of the first things I would do is to remove that background thread from the ASP.NET application. It doesn't belong there.

Comment: @John Rasch: I have `edited` my question and added my main function and the functions which are getting called for downloading and parsing the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many things wrong with your code:

- You have all sorts of objects which implement `IDisposable`, and you're not placing them into `using` blocks. For instance,

  OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

should be

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    // ...
}
```

- Do not catch exceptions that you cannot handle.

Comment: 2. don't use string building for queries.  SQL Injection is bad, m'kay?

Comment: MySqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();
while (result.Read())
{
  LTPDatabase = Convert.ToDecimal(result[0]);
}
This code is just silly.  Loop through a result set to get a single value?

Long term you're going to need to queue these up likely rather than make it synchronous.

Comment: @John Saunders: What code should I write inside `using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())`?

Comment: @Sean: What is the alternative to this Silly code? `while (result.Read()) { LTPDatabase = Convert.ToDecimal(result[0]); }`?

Comment: @PARTH: make your query return the record you want.  Either select id from table where x=y or select max(column) from y where a=b and then simply run a ExecuteScalar to get a single result back.  To answer your question to @John Saunders, any code that will be using the reader should be in the using block, as the reader will be destroyed once the block ends.

Comment: @Sean: ok thanks for the solution you gave for my question to @John

Comment: @Sean: What should be the datatype for the receiver variable in ExecuteScalar? should it be MySQLDataReader?

Comment: It typically is an object.  You'll typically cast it to an int (if it's an int) or ToString() it to get a string.  Depends on what the type of the result of the query is.  The documentation for the MySql connector would be a good place to start: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executescalar

Comment: @Sean : Also do point out more mistakes in the code if they are ought to create a delay.

Comment: @PARTH: all the code that depends on `reader` should be inside the `using` block for `reader`.

Comment: @PARTH there's so much about this code that I'd do differently I don't know where to start honestly.  First I'd ask why you want a user to be waiting 30+ seconds for you to process some CSV rather than queueing it up and doing it asynchronously.

Comment: @Sean: how should I carry it out asynchronously??

Comment: @PARTH write it to a MSMQ (or other queue) and have it processed independently of the web application... but without knowing WHY you're doing the CSV processing, I can't make any real recommendations.

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for the input. Our app is a stock market application and there is a need to update the stock quotes everytime so I am downloading and parsing the CSV to update the database. Hope now it is more clear to you why all this CSV processing is done.

Comment: @John Saunders: Thanks got the purpose of using `using` block

Comment: @PARTH As @John Saunders said in the question comments, I'd pull this thread/processing out of ASP.NET and put it into a windows service.  This service could then run continuously without impacting ASP.NET, downloading and processing the .CSV files.  I'd put some timing logic into the code and see what's actually taking the longest.  My bet is that it's not the bit of code you've posted, but rather in the newService.CSVInsert(IndexCode,Index,MarketOpen,Bid,Offer,LastTradePrice);